# find two values from same column in same quote

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to join the same table twice with no succes. I have two tables.

table1

- Id
- replacer
- replacedBy

table2

- ProductID
- ProductName

How can I in the same query join table2 twice, so I can see

```
Replacer ProductName and replacedBy ProductName
```

I have tried inner join but can only get the product name belonging to "replacedBy". How can I join two times so I can see productnames belonging to "replacedBy" and "replacer"

select

table1.Replacer,
table1.ReplacedBy,
table2.productname

from table1

inner join table2 on table1.ReplacedBy = Standards.ProjectNr
;

Comment: What is `Standards.ProjectNr`? You don't define the column above.

Comment: What is Standards.ProjectNr?

Comment: Why do you try to join `table1` and `table2` using table `Standards` in `ON` statement?

Comment: I'm _guessing_ that the OP intended to replace `Standards` with his dummy table/column names, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Standards.ProjectNr` was an editing error that you intended to replace with your dummy `table.column` names, then you might try this:

```sql
    SELECT t1.id, r.ProductID as replacer_ID,  r.ProductName as replacer,
        b.ProductID as replacedBy_ID, b.ProductName as replacedByName
        FROM table1 t1
        INNER JOIN table2 r ON t1.replacer = r.ProductID
        INNER JOIN table2 b ON t1.replacedBy = b.ProductID
```

If you want all the IDs from table1, then you should replace the `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`.

But again, sample data would be good.